# Definition of Dye- Reduction Test?

Tags: biochemistry, genetics, pharmacology, microbiology, terminology

Can some one give a simple explanation or definition on what a **dye-reduction test** is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dye reduction tests (and there seem to be loads of different ones) are simply assays in which a dye becomes decolourised to give you a visual indication of whether a certain process is occuring. [Here](http://www.vet.cmu.ac.th/webmed/branch/web%20department/ck/mastitis/Milk%20quality/resazurin.pdf) you can find an example of a dye reduction test with Methylene Blue and Reazurin which indirectly measures the bacterial densities in milk and cream. See this [google book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f--1V1ftgtsC&pg=RA1-PA94&lpg=RA1-PA94&dq=Methylene%20Blue%20and%20Resazurin%20bacteria%20in%20milk&source=bl&ots=pYN6kN5Ivr&sig=87Ghg8hihFhdVHdTT-juL7R_2SE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6-BbUY2YIcrT0QXG-IGoDQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Methylene%20Blue%20and%20Resazurin%20bacteria%20in%20milk&f=false) for more info.